# Un-delete of questions that have been edited to comply AND an answer has been given

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366412/sum-up-2-arrays-considering-their-decimal-values) was deleted because several users could not determine the question/problem behind the OP. Well, I was able to figure it out as well as give a complete and accurate answer. It also appears that the author has edited the OP to now comply.

Does this question even show up for those that have not taken part in it (commented/voted/answered)? What if no one involved was a 10K and therefore no one knows it's eligible for undeletion? Is there / should there be a way to alert moderators / 10Ks to reconsider the question for resurrection?

Comment: The question isn't deleted.

Comment: Nor has the OP (question) been edited at all. Certainly not to 'comply'.

Comment: @Mysticial Ok, [on-hold] pending deletion, then.

Comment: `[on hold]` means pending closure, not deletion.

Comment: @DevlshOne  Not really; On-Hold, pending Close. Wherein it can *still* be improved. In fact, even after deletion, it could be improved. But with up-voted answers, it's not necessarily guaranteed to be deleted, anyway.

Comment: Besides, the on-hold reason isn't related to us not understanding the problem.

Comment: That question is clearly requesting that someone do their work for them. It is a feature request from a help vampire. Answering these types of questions only encourage others to post the same type of poor quality content.

Comment: As one of the users who voted to close it.... It's one of the more blatant "Here's my homework, can someone do it for me?" questions I've seen, with nothing in the question to show any effort on behalf of the OP.

Comment: @andrewsi Well the OP did say "I have tried some things..."  ;)

Comment: Well, it's deleted now.

Comment: That'll teach me not to waste my time with crappy questions.

Comment: The question was reposted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372986/summation-addition-of-two-arrays-particular).

Comment: @Dev That's kinda the point...

Answer (score 10):

Yes, that question is visible to all and sundry. It may well be deleted eventually, but it hasn't been deleted *yet* - it's been placed on hold, in the hope that someone will put some time in and address the problems with it. *If* that happens, it can be re-opened and will no longer be as easily removed from the site.

**So edit the question!** Make it look like someone who knew what they were asking and had the ability to communicate this wrote it. Re-write it from top to bottom, if you need to - make it something you'd be proud to have your name on...

*Then* see what happens.

If all that seems like too much to do, then I recommend not answering such poor-quality questions in the future.

Comment: I was in the middle of editing when it was deleted.

Comment: Restored, left a comment, please continue editing.

Comment: Finished editing. I got as close to compliance as I could without being libelous.